# The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Urun>.this[int]' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, list, generics, collections, system

```
public Urun(int id)
        {
            this.UrunId = id;

            List<Urun> dr = ManagementLib.UrunBilgisiAl(id, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);


            for (int i = 0; i < dr.Count; i++)
            {


                this.UrunId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"].ToString());
```

......

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.this[int]' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from `String` to `int`

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` does not support lookup by key. You need to use a `Dictionary<string, URun>`

Comment: thanks your answer. my method is return ListItem...another way ?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. You may wish to edit your question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

> Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.this[int]' has some invalid arguments

You're trying to access items on `List<Urun>` as a dictionary and that's not possible

```
dr["id"] //<-- this is not valid, a position is expected (dr[0], dr[1], etc)
```

I assume you're trying to do

```
this.UrunId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[i].id.ToString());
```

But I don't see the point honestly since on every iteration `this.UrunId` would be overwritten.

Comment: build succeeded. would continue. take some time. I write as a result...thanks by the way...